# Filtering rows and eliminating the odd one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

After writing complex queries, I am putting columns values into #temp table

```
            // Complex business logic code
            ...
            ...
             SELECT Distinct
             Jurisdiction,
             JurisdictionX,
             LicenceNumber,
             DateIssued,
             ExpirationDate,
             Resident
             FROM #TEMP
```

Now it's giving result very close to my actual solution as shown in the image...

[image]

See the above image, in it there are 6 columns

if you notice that there are two rows with the same state "Alabama". In one row license number, DateIssued and ExpirationDate columns are empty. In the second  row license number, DateIssued and ExpirationDate columns are having values. Now I want that in such situation it should consider the second row where license number, DateIssued and ExpirationDate columns are having values and it should eliminate the other one where license number, DateIssued and ExpirationDate columns are empty.

Can any one please help in writting query for it???

Comment: I think what you are looking is `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Actually I want programming structures like loop, if else in sql. I think it will resolve my problem... Please help me how !!!

Comment: SQL is a set based language. Loops are best avoided, the performance is terrible at scale. If you post your code we could help you refactor your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT Distinct Jurisdiction, JurisdictionX, LicenceNumber, DateIssued, ExpirationDate, Resident
FROM #TEMP
WHERE LicenseNumber IS NOT NULL AND 
      DateIssued IS NOT NULL AND 
      ExpirationDate IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT Distinct Jurisdiction, JurisdictionX, LicenceNumber, DateIssued, ExpirationDate, Resident
FROM #TEMP
WHERE JurisdictionX NOT IN ( SELECT JurisdictionX from #TEMP
      WHERE LicenseNumber IS NOT NULL AND 
            DateIssued IS NOT NULL AND 
            ExpirationDate IS NOT NULL);
```